# Write two equations with their individual equation numbers in consecutive lines

Tags: math-mode

I have to write two equations in two consecutive lines and each equation should get its equation number as well. When I write using the following method, both the equation appears in the same line with one common equation number.

```
\begin{equation}
  E = m \\
  x = y
\end{equation}
```

I want to get something like following:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried:
 `\begin{equation} E=m \end{equation} \begin{equation}x = y\end{equation}` ?

Comment: `\begin{gather} E=m \\ x = y \end{gather}`?

Comment: ``\begin{equation} E=m \end{equation} \begin{equation}x = y\end{equation}`  will write the two equations with a line break between them. I want that both the equations should appear in consequetive lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to go there:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    E = m \\
    x = y
\end{gather}  
\begin{equation}
    E = m
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
    x = y
\end{equation} 
\begin{align}
    E &= m \\
    x &= y
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I suppose, you are not willing to do the middle approach so you should explain more specific, what you want to get, what you have tried so far, and where you had problems to succeed. This homepage is full of equations with different alignments, groupings (like above) or multiline equations with `split`, `multline`, and so on...